# Linux while read loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function doPing () {
    pings=0

    #cat /home/scripts/test.txt | while read server ; do
    #while [ $pings -le 3 ] ; do
        echo success1 $pings
        if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then {
            pings=$(expr $pings + 1)
            echo success- $pings
        } else if [ 1 -eq 2 ]; then {
            pings=$(expr $pings + 1)
            echo not
        } else {
            pings=$(expr $pings + 1)
            echo known
        } fi
        fi

        echo success3 $pings
    done

    echo -e "\nSuccessfully pinged $pings.\n"
}

doPing
```

test.txt contains a few lines of server names, it does not matter actually.

My problem is that when I uncomment the line `#while ...`, I get:

```
success1 0
success- 1
success3 1
success1 1
success- 2
success3 2
success1 2
success- 3
success3 3
success1 3
success- 4
success3 4
success1 4
success- 5
success3 5

Successfully pinged 0.
```

but when I uncomment the line `#cat ...`, I get:

```
success1 0
success- 1
success3 1
success1 1
success- 2
success3 2
success1 2
success- 3
success3 3
success1 3
success- 4
success3 4

Successfully pinged 4.
```

How can I make it so that the `#while` output will be some number pinged, like `#cat ...`, not zero? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This is knit-picky (and not your problem), but you may want to adjust `#!/bin/bash` to be `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.  That's more portable to other systems as it uses `bash` that's specified by the environmental vars.  As far as the issue, I bet someone will beat me to an answer - but I am looking at it locally now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the pipe creates a subshell and changes to a variable in a subshell does not propagate to the parent.

For more information read [this explanation about variables in pipelines](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: ...and the solution is simple: remove the useless use of `cat`! Don't use a pipeline, use `while ... done </home/scripts/test.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
...
while read value ; do
...
done < /home/scripts/test.txt
...
```

… although I do not know what `-r` means after `read`.

Comment: Yes, but what is the practical implication of this, that is what I do not get yet. Can it be that file then looks as one big line, even if in reality has more then one line? Thank you